# Drawing dotted (....)trail path instead of a line (________)

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, bitmap, android-canvas

Now below is my code that draws path between geopoints in map. This works perfectly fine. What I'm trying to implement is instead of drawing  a line,display this path with the dots(.) as in iPhone. I want it to be like this gp1.........gp2  instead of drawing in a single straight line like  gp1_***_*__*_***_gp2.

I have tried almost all the options for doing this but still no success on this, any one can help me solving this?

```
private void drawPath(List geoPoints, int color) {
    List overlays = objMapView.getOverlays();
    int loopcount = geoPoints.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++) {
        GeoPoint p1 = (GeoPoint) geoPoints.get(i);
        GeoPoint p2 = (GeoPoint) geoPoints.get(i + 1);
        MyPathOverLay p = null;
        /**** Marking the start and end of the trailpath ****/
        if (i == 0) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.greenflag);
            p = new MyPathOverLay(p1, p2, 0xFFFF0000, true, false, bmp);
        } else if (i == loopcount - 1) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.redflag);
            p = new MyPathOverLay(p1, p2, 0xFFFF0000, false, true, bmp);
        } else {
            p = new MyPathOverLay(p1, p2, 0xFFFF0000, false, false, null);
        }
        overlays.add(p);
    }
}



public class MyPathOverLay extends Overlay {

private GeoPoint gp1;
private GeoPoint gp2;
private int color;
Boolean  isFirstPOI;
Boolean isLastPOI;
AudioMap audioMap;
Bitmap bmp;

public MyPathOverLay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2, int color,Boolean first, Boolean last,Bitmap bitMap) {
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
    this.color = color;
    this.isFirstPOI= first;
    this.isLastPOI = last;
    this.bmp = bitMap;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Point point = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
    paint.setColor(color);
    Point point2 = new Point();
    projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setAlpha(120);
    canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x, point2.y, paint);
  //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
    Point screenPts = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(gp1, screenPts);
    //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
    Point screenPts1 = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(gp2, screenPts1);
    if(isFirstPOI == true){
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,screenPts.x-20,screenPts.y-40, null);  
    }
    else if(isLastPOI == true) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp,screenPts1.x-20,screenPts1.y-35, null);  
   }
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167236/canvas-drawlines-displaying-disjointed-segments

Comment: Is this question using an old google maps api (at the moment of writing this  comment, the current one is v2)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to this guy, I referred this example and it is working for me.

[How do I make a dotted/dashed line in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android)

Just need to add these 2 lines,

```
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,10}, 5));
    canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x, point2.y, paint);
```

after I set,

```
    paint.setAlpha(120);
```

@Frankenstein, thank you

Comment: You also can accept your own answers :) , Also care to put your code if you find it necessary...cheers

Comment: @Frankenstein, I can accept my own answer after 2 days only :( Not much changes I did to the code, I just added those 2 lines fgPaintSel.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
fgPaintSel.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,20}, 0)); after I set alpha for the paint