# How to draw dotted lines between geopoints in google map on android

Tags: java, android

I have displayed the locations on map with marker images, but now i want to connect the locations by dotted lines, in same line locations.

Please give any idea....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer,

[drawing-dotted-trail-path-instead-of-a-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android)

Implementation for the same is [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185445/drawing-dotted-trail-path-instead-of-a-line)